# How to dynamically create partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a table in my database called Programs. I want to display a tab for each program .I am trying to create a partial view to do this and then I want to include the partial view to every view that will need to have those tabs. My partial view looks like below.

```
<div id="tabs">

    <ul>
        <li id="HomeTab">@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li id="Program1Tab">@Html.ActionLink("Program1", "Index", "Program")</li>
        <li id="Program2Tab">@Html.ActionLink("Program2", "Index", "Program")</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am hoping to dynamically create the tabs using something like

```
  @foreach (var ptype in Model)
    {
       <li id=\"@ptype.Name\"Tab>@Html.ActionLink(ptype.Name, "Index", "Project")</li>
    }
```

however I am wondering how I can load the tabs without using a controller. Can I use a helper class/method to directly access the model bypassing the controller?

update:
I also tried by creating a helper method

```
namespace MyProject.Helpers
{
    public class ProgramTypes
    {
        public static List<ProgramType> ProgramTypesList()
        {
            MyDbContext db = new myDbContext();
            return db.ProgramTypes.ToList<Programtype>();

        }
    }
}
```

and then accessing them using

```
 @foreach (var ptype in MyProject.Helpers.ProgramTypes.ProgramTypesList())
```

however i am not sure if this is the correct thing to do.

Comment: just added some more code.see above

Comment: Did you look at editor templates ?

Comment: yes. I have used Editor Templates. They are still"Views" and have no access to the model directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is - passing collection of programs to your view

```
@model IQueyrable<Program>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    @foreach (var ptype in Model)
    {
       <li>@Html.RenderPartial("ProgramTab", ptype)</li>
    }
    </ul>
</div>
```

so you have to create another partial view where you will display program details.
If you want organize this like tabs you should use something like jquery tabs

**you don't have to use actionlink just RenderPartial or RenderAction**

Comment: you don't have to use actionlink just renderpartial or renderaction

Comment: great idea to user RenderAction. Thank you @Bohdan

Comment: sort of though noone anwered my original question if what I was doing was wrong or not